# App rejected for offering Apple products as a contest prize?

Tags: ios, app-store

Recently my app was rejected because of using Apple products (iPhone, iPad,etc) as a price of the contest. Below is the reason which is given by the Apple review team for rejection.

> We found that your app includes a contest which provides Apple products as 
>   prizes.Apps that include such offerings incorrectly create an association with 
>    Apple, Inc. and are not in compliance with the App Store Review Guidelines.

As per review guidelines, I updated my Terms & Conditions saying that the contest is not related to Apple in any way and so on. Below is the T&C which I provided.

> Terms and Conditions: Promotion runs from 15/07/2013 – 31/8/2013. To qualify for this promotion consumers must purchase any product from the Hill’s Science Diet™ pet food range in one transaction to the value of $15 or more. Proof of purchase is required to enter the competition. There is 1 Apple®, iPad Mini®, Apple TV®, iPod Nano® and $100 iTunes Gift Card® to be won per Indepet store throughout Australia. Participating clinics must have a copy of the full terms and conditions (to be supplied by Hill’s Pet Nutrition) at the clinic counter for consumers to access. Apple® is not a participant in or a sponsor of this promotion

Again I resubmitted my app and it's rejected this time too, saying the same reason. Am I doing anything wrong? Shouldn't we use any Apple product as a price of competitions? Please share your idea so I can use Apple products as a prices.

Should I provide any clear information regarding the contest?

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about the Apple app store validation process; not programming techniques or tools

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> We found that your app includes a contest which provides Apple products as prizes. Apps that include such offerings incorrectly create an association with Apple, Inc. and are not in compliance with the App Store Review Guidelines.

I read this to mean *you may not offer any Apple products as prizes in any contests you run in your app*. It doesn't matter that you say that Apple's not involved. You just can't offer Apple products.

Comment: I hear that Surface RTs can be had for cheap, though...

Comment: So should I remove offering apple products? But in the review guidelines, its not mentioned anything about "we should not use apple products as a price in our apple".Please refer point no 20 in the following webpage "https://developer.apple.com/appstore/resources/approval/guidelines.html"

Comment: Yes, @NSUserDefault, you should remove Apple products from the contest. Note that Apple's guidelines aren't intended to be all-inclusive.

Comment: (The passive voice is funny, for non-native English speakers, as I assume NSUserDefault is. The quoted text in the rejection logically lead to the unstated conclusion "Don't offer Apple products as contest prizes".)

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion.But if I set apple products as a price once my app got approved, will it be a any problem?

Comment: I don't know, @NSUserDefault. You'd be playing a risky game, since you already know Apple frowns on that activity. And what happens if you need to deploy an update?

Comment: OK thank you very much... I will remove that option and re-submit my app.